# Generate weekly event in user order

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I'm working on something where you can schedule events and assign them to people.
I want these events to occur weekly and automatically assign them.

For example:

```
week 1 events 1 - person 1
       events 2 - person 2
       events 3 - person 3

week 2 events 1 - person 4
       -------------------
       events 2 - person 1
       events 3 - person 2

week 3 events 1 - person 3
       events 2 - person 4
       events 3 - person 1
       ...so on
```

The thing that I can't wrap my head around is how to continue assigning the events to the next person in a new week.

How should I approach this problem? I'm building this in React with Node.js as the backend. This will be handled in the backend.

Thank you for your reply in advance.

Comment: What have you come up with?

Comment: @RobertRocha I've added a dash in the code section. In my code, I'm just testing ideas on how to work this out and I figured it out till the dash. It works by iterating through the members and assigning them an event but I need it to continue.